# App running in Intellij-IDEA is extremely slow

Tags: performance, intellij-idea, runtime

I have an app which I want to run in intellij-idea using run button. The task which everyone of us do almost every day. Yesterday everything was working fine but today it is somehow extremely slow. It will get built fast but when it is being run it is extremely slow.

I have no other big processes running, it is just intellij-idea.

My app is gradle project. When I build it and start it using gradlew everything is smooth as it was yesterday. I have the latest version of intellij-idea ultimate. Also I have tried reinstalling it but the problem remains the same.

Can someone help me with what might cause this problem ?

I was searching all day for the answer but I am not able to find any. It is frustrating.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Could you please clarify what do you mean by "when it is being run it is extremely slow."? What application do you run?

Comment: It is spring boot web project. It is simply extremely slow so slow I can not do anything it takes like 6 minutes to start up (after all endpoints are mapped etc.) but before that it was like 20s. But also on very simple spring boot app (I was testing that) with just one main class it takes soo much time to run- around 2 minutes.

Comment: Remove debugging breakpoints?

Comment: I have tried that but it is not working.